# Three.js, Macintosh Display 3D Model

Tags: three.js

I created a 3D model in Blender.
I exported it with the exporter and the convert_obj_three.py (both did export fine, but did not show in the browser, with the code below).

I used the code below html/js from here:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/porting-3d-graphics-to-the-web-webgl-intro-part-2/

The original demo/any other three.js example from the site works fine in Firefox (Mac OS X 10.6.8, AMD Radeon HD 6490M).

All other browser seem to have a problem.

Interestingly if I run a simple:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888

from any example directory and want to look at it via Firefox, it does not work/render either.

I always get the background color and the text, but no rendering.

And all required three .js are in the same directory.

Am I missing something or is this just random ?

How can I display a simple 3D model, that can be rotated by the user ?
Is this code correct ?

Thx.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>WebGL made easy</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background:#fff;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                font-family:'trebuchet ms', 'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-align:center;
            }
            canvas { pointer-events:none; z-index:10; }

            p { font-size: small;}

        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <script src="Three.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="RequestAnimationFrame.js"></script>

            <script>
            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            var FLOOR = 0;

            var container;

            var camera, scene;
            var webglRenderer;

            var zmesh, geometry;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                // camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000 );
                camera.position.z = 75;

                //scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // lights
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
                scene.add( ambient );

                // more lights
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, -70, 100 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // renderer
                webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                webglRenderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
                container.appendChild( webglRenderer.domElement );

                // loader
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
                callbackModel   = function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry,  90, FLOOR, -50, 105 ) };
                loader.load( { model: "mymodel.js", callback: callbackModel } );
            }

            function createScene( geometry, x, y, z, b ) {

                zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
                zmesh.position.set( 0, 16, 0 );
                zmesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( zmesh );
            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            function render() {

                zmesh.rotation.set(-mouseY/500 + 1, -mouseX/200, 0);

                webglRenderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the Error console of Firefox I get:Error: TypeError: url.split is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and the issue lies with your loader callback functionality. Try this instead:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    callbackModel = function(geometry, materials) { createScene( geometry, materials, 90, FLOOR, -50, 105 ) };
loader.load( "cubeHelper.js", callbackModel );
```

Notice the addition of the `materials` parameter, and of course add `materials` to the function parameters for createScene like so:

```
function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, b ) {
    zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff0000 } ) );
    zmesh.position.set( 0, 16, 0 );
    zmesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
    scene.add( zmesh );
}
```

Notice that I change `MeshFaceMaterial` to `MeshBasicMaterial` this is because MeshFaceMaterial needs and array of materials like that coming into the createScene, so when your ready you can create a material from the incoming `materials` and apply at that point. But that will get you going.